# rotate svg and fit it to browser window

Tags: html, css, svg

Hy i have following svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200" width="100" height="200" >
<g>
    <rect style="fill:#000000;" id="spinner" width="100" height="200"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="80" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="180" fill="white">Stau 800m</text>
</g>
```

I set with and height to 100% in a stylesheet:

```
svg{width:100%; height:100%}
```

If i display the svg in browser the svg is scaled to the size of the browser.
After that i want to rotate the svg. so i adapted the stylesheet.

```
svg{width:100%; height:100%; transform: rotate(90deg);}
```

The svg is then rotated but it is not scaled correctly:

[image]

As you can see in the picture there is a blank space on the top and on the bottom.
The svg does not use the full size of the browser window.

Can you help me? What do i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the viewBox will stay the same when you rotate the SVG. If you change the viewBox so that the width is 200 and the height is 100 the content (`<g>`) can just be rotated and translated.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <g transform="rotate(90) translate(0 -200)">
    <rect style="fill:#000000;" id="spinner" width="100" height="200"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="80" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="180" fill="white">Stau 800m</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Update

And doing the transform with CSS (but the viewBox needs to be done as an attribute):

```css
svg > g {
 transform: rotate(90deg) translatey(-200px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <g>
    <rect style="fill:#000000;" id="spinner" width="100" height="200"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <circle style="fill:#ffff00;" cx="80" cy="20" r="10"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="180" fill="white">Stau 800m</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast support. is it also possible to make this changes in an stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

But why rotate at all?

I presume your objective is to align the text (correct for every distance)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

Using a native JavaScript Web Component ***with*** shadowDOM, so none of the SVG content interferes with other SVGs on the same page (notably the `id="#P"` to position the text)

If you want to draw the text aligned/spaced with the circles, add a `textLength="8"` to the `<textPath>`

```html
<traffic-jam distance="800"></traffic-jam>
<traffic-jam distance="1200"></traffic-jam>

<script>
  customElements.define('traffic-jam',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.style.display = "inline-block";
        let distance = Number(this.getAttribute("distance"));
        let color = distance < 1000 ? "red" : "yellow";
        let svg = `<svg style="width:100%" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
                    <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    <g fill="${color}" transform="translate(16)">
                      <circle cy="2" r="1" />
                      <circle cy="8" r="1" />
                    </g>
                    <path id="P" pathLength="2" d="M4 0V10" stroke="none"/>
                    <text>
                     <textPath font-size=".1em" font-family="arial"
                               href="#P" startoffset="1" text-anchor="middle"
                               fill="white">Stau ${distance}m</textPath>
                    </text>
                  </svg>`
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = svg;
      };
    })
</script>
```

Comment: we have for each distance or text a own svg. this is given by the customer but we have to rotate the svg.

Comment: Then the customer has a designer who blunty outputs SVGs, without much understanding what them our doing.. Offer you customer to do it [creating SVGS yourself] half-price.